# systemd mount unit name different on different VMs

Tags: systemd, ubuntu-18.04

I see that on some VMs, the unit that mounts *hugepages* is called `mnt-huge` on some and just `huge` on others:

```
# systemctl list-units | grep huge 
mnt-huge.mount            loaded active mounted   /mnt/huge
```

Is there a way to change this (make it uniform) ?

```
# systemctl list-units | grep huge
huge.mount             loaded active mounted   /huge
```

The version of `systemd` is same on both these VMs (and both running Ubuntu `18.04.4`)

Answer (score 0):

Found it! I had to modify `/etc/fstab` to have `/mnt/huge` instead of `/huge`!